# C program Reading Hex values from Fat MBR

Tags: c, hex, fat16

I am new to the C language and am trying to create a forensic tool. So far i have this. It reads a dd file which is a dump of a fat16 MBR. I am able to read certain bytes properly but not some.

What i need help with is the SizeOfFat variable needs to get the values of byte 0x16 and 0x17 read in little endian. How would i have it read FB00 and then convert it to 00FB and then print the value ?

```
char buf[64];
int startFat16 = part_entry[0].start_sect,sectorSize = 512,dirEntrySize=32;
fseek(fp, startFat16*512, SEEK_SET);
fread(buf, 1, 64, fp);

int rootDir = *(int*)(buf+0x11);
int sectorPerCluster = *(int*)(buf+0x0D);
int sizeOfFat = *(int*)(buf+0x16);
int fatCopies = *(int*)(buf+0x10);  
printf("\n Phase 2 \n no of sectors per cluster : %d \n",(unsigned char)sectorPerCluster);
printf("size of fat : %d \n",(unsigned char)sizeOfFat);
printf("no of Fat copies : %d \n",(unsigned char)fatCopies);
printf("maximum number of root directories : %d \n",(unsigned char)rootDir);
```

The hex values im working with here are -

```
EB 3C 90 4D 53 44 4F 53 35 2E 30 00 02 08 02 00 
02 00 02 00 00 F8 FB 00 3F 00 FF 00 3F 00 00 00
E1 D7 07 00 80 00 29 CD 31 52 F4 4E 4F 20 4E 41
```

Comment: What is `fp`? Some `/dev/` special file? Just curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `int`, you only got the guarantee that it can hold 32-bit signed integers. With your code, you read `sizeof(int)` bytes for every of your variables, even though they differ in size. There are `uint16_t`, `uint8_t`, `uint32_t` types on most systems. Use those for fixed-width data. Note also that they are unsigned. You don't want negative sectors per cluster, do you?

Comment: Do not need negative sectors at the moment. Another thing would be how can i store two bytes into the variable in little endian ? Sorry if that seems crude.

Comment: @C0d3ine Of course you don't, that was rhetorical. :-) I'm telling you should use unsigned data types here. Regarding the two bytes -- there is `uint16_t`. This type holds exactly 16 bits or two bytes on x86. Use this for your cast and to store two-byte data. Endianess... since it's x86, which is little-endian, I assume the FAT metadata on disk is stored in little-endian as well. So just do the cast, you'll get correct results, since your compiler expects little-endian and the data you retrieve is little-endian.

Comment: Right. okay edited the question a bit. My understanding was way off. Hahaa. My bad.

Comment: i had a misunderstanding thinking the two bytes were read for sizeOfFat and in little endian. turns out it just read the 0x16 offset byte. So edited teh question.

Comment: @C0d3ine Look at [that](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/linux/msdos_fs.h) from bleeding-edge Linux. See the `struct fat_boot_sector` definition? No `int`, no `short`... just fixed-width data types. And unsigned.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. It all started making sense now. Was looking at it different.